# Splitting float string in Go regex

Tags: regex, string, go

I'm, trying to split a certain string type to its constituents using Golang's regex.

What I have is a `Sprinf(".2f", n)` of any given float (to simplify it to 2 decimal places), and would wish to separate the hundredths digit like:

```
"1.25" = ["1.2", "5"]
"1.99" = ["1.9", "9"]
```

In PHP, this is something like:

```
preg_match('/^ (\-? \d [.] \d) (\d) $/x', sprintf('%1.2f', $input), $matches)
```

and I can get the parts via $matches[0] and $matches[1].

Tried it with :

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`/^ (\-? \d [.] \d) (\d) $/x`)
fmt.Printf("%q\n", re.FindAllStringSubmatch("1.50", 2))
```

to no avail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try it without the spaces? `^(\-?\d[.]\d)(\d)$` See https://regex101.com/r/8rLiLk/2

Comment: thanks mate..tried it with regexp.MustCompile(`^(\-?\d[.]\d)(\d)$`) and it works..

Comment: `x` is not a supported flag in RE2: https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax#Flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need regexp for this? Simply slice the string:

```
func split(s string) []string {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    return []string{s[:len(s)-1], s[len(s)-1:]}
}
```

Testing it:

```
nums := []string{
    fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", 1.25),
    fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", 1.99),
    fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", 1.25),
    fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", 1.2),
    fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", 0.0),
    fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", -1.2),
    "",
}
for _, n := range nums {
    fmt.Printf("%q = %q\n", n, split(n))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IrnnIAe9x-b)):

```
"1.25" = ["1.2" "5"]
"1.99" = ["1.9" "9"]
"1.25" = ["1.2" "5"]
"1.20" = ["1.2" "0"]
"0.00" = ["0.0" "0"]
"-1.20" = ["-1.2" "0"]
"" = []
```